# How to quit PyQT QThread automatically when it is done?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I want a sound to play when I click a button in PyQT5.

Playing a sound appears to be a blocking operation, so GUI is unresponsive. Thus I want to start a new thread, play sound, and delete the thread, all in a non-blocking manner.

I create a thread class

```
class playSoundThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, soundpath):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.soundpath = soundpath

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()
        print("Thread exited")

    def run(self):
        playsound(self.soundpath)
```

And run it as follows

```
class MainClass(...):
    ...

    def playsound(self, soundKey):
        self.thisSoundThread = playSoundThread(self.sounds[soundKey])
        self.thisSoundThread.start()
```

Everything works fine and is non-blocking. The only problem is that the thread does not get deleted when the sound stops playing. I have tried calling `del self.thisSoundThread`, but this operation seems to be blocking, defeating the point.

What is the correct way to exit a thread after completion in a non-blocking way?

Comment: You should add code that runs later on: `self.thisSound.wait(); self.thisSound = None;`  Also, just don't have a `__del__(self):` method in your classes.

Comment: Use [QSound](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html). It's dead simple, and it doesn't require multi-threading.

Comment: @ekhumoro I will likely follow your advice. `pydub` which I am using at the moment seems to also have problems with terminating sounds half way, they continue even after I have attempted to delete the thread. Still, it appreciate learning about threads a bit

Comment: @ekhumoro, sorry for late reply, I finally got to try it. QSound actually seems to perform worse than multithreading, because it has at least 1 second lag between calling QSound.play() and the actual result, which is annoying. Not sure how to fix it, most recent answer on this topic is from 2011. Gonna stick with threading now

Comment: @AleksejsFomins For me (on arch linux) the sounds play instantly with no perceptible delay. The docs say creating a `QSound` object and calling the `play()` slot may play more immediately on some systems than using the static function. However, for me, they both play instantly (even with a 40Mb wav file). I suppose a slow device (e.g. a network drive or an old hard-disk) might introduce a slight delay when using the static function with a large file. Using a `QSound` object will pre-load the file into memory, so it should be more performant.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks for giving it a try. I will try to create a QSound object, and experiment with different extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it should get deleted? I do not see any call of "del" and you assign it into instance so GC also doesnt because there is still existing reference.

If you want to delete it you have to do something like this:

```
class MainClass(...):
    ...

    def playsound(self, soundKey):
        self.thisSoundThread = playSoundThread(self.sounds[soundKey])
        self.thisSoundThread.finished.connect(self.threadfinished)
        self.thisSoundThread.start()

    def threadfinished(self)
        del self.thisSoundThread
        # or set it to None
```

Comment: As I said, I did try `del self.thisSoundThread`, but it was blocking. I did not know about `finished` event, it words. So thanks :)